# sp_who2 'active' shows select that starts at 2147483647cpu time and that blocks itself

Tags: sql-server

I was checking an occurrence of a large number of batch requests from an application and noticed that, while not doing any heavy reading or writing it showed a CPU time of 2147483647 immediately after being started.

like this

[image]

I understand that the problem is on the application itself, but I don't understand why it is showing the 2147483647 CPU time and why the process can be SUSPENDED and RUNNABLE at the same time.
Is there any way I can optimize this using just the database since I don't have access to the application itself

Comment: Because sp_who2 is garbage and you shouldn’t use it for any serious troubleshooting. Use [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) instead.

Comment: @ErikDarling Lol fair enough, but I will say I've recently experienced the same exact issue as OP when using Adam Machanic's `sp_WhoIsActive`. It actually happens fairly commonly for me, and usually the `start_time` column returns the min value of a `DATETIME` on the same record too. Never saw this happen in older versions of SQL Server, so not sure if the DMVs changed in 2016+ that could be affecting this?

Comment: @J.D. you should [open an issue](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/issues) when things like that happen.

Comment: @ErikDarling Will do, thanks. I did some quick research, and does seem to be an *issue* on Microsoft's end / them defaulting to the max value of the `INT` data type of 2,147,483,647 when unable to provide a value in certain cases. But I'll let Adam know too, maybe there's a workaround out there.